# creating xtype in Ext.Define and calling it in TabPanel items:[]

Tags: extjs, tabs, extjs4

I am new to extjs in general, specially to 4 version:

I have created a class:

```
Ext.define('MyPanel', {
    extend:'Ext.panel.Panel',
    views: ["MyPanel"],

    config: {
        width: 200,
        height: 300,
        title: "HELLO"
    },

    constructor:function(config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
        return this;
    },
    alias: 'widget.MyPanel'
});
```

Next, I want to call this class in form of XTYPE in a tabPanel items:[]:
I did like this:

```
items: [{
    title: 'Kontakt',
    id: 'kontaktTab',
    closable:true,
    closeAction: 'hide',
    layout: 'fit',
    items:[{
            xtype: "MyPanel"
        }]
```

No luck yet, all I get is :
`Cannot create an instance of unrecognized alias: widget.MyPanel"`
You must think, what a noob....
;-)

Someone please help!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hrm, have you tried lowercasing your alias. I thought aliases were always stored and fetched lowercase, but not sure about it

Comment: Yes I did, no luck there, also!

Comment: i can confirm - this is a correct answer, it works for me, Ext JS really does not allow capitalization in the name of the view.

Answer (score 7):

When you are defining your view (MyPanel), why have you set `views` property?

```
Ext.define('MyPanel', {
    extend:'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.MyPanel'
    views: ["MyPanel"],    <------ Why do you need this???
    config: {
        width: 200,
        height: 300,
        title: "HELLO"
    },
    constructor:function(config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
        return this;
    }
});
```

And when you are making use of the new view, you need to specify it in `requires`. Here is an example:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Viewport',{
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport', 
    layout: 'border',
    requires: [
        'MyPanel'       <--- This will ensure that this view file needs to be loaded
    ],  
    .
    .
    .
    items: [{
        title: 'Kontakt',
        id: 'kontaktTab',
        closable:true,
        closeAction: 'hide',
        layout: 'fit',
        items:[{
            xtype: "MyPanel"
        }]
```

Answer (score 4):

Ah, hehe, I completely overlooked something:

with an 'alias' you are creating a new class reference in the ExtJS class list. So by adding the alias like you did above, you can instantiate it by calling

```
var newMyPanel = Ext.create('widget.MyPanel');
```

However, if you are adding an instance with a xtype specifier you have to omit the widget part and just do:

```
var myContainer = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
    items: [{
        xtype: 'MyPanel'
    }]
});
```

With the above code, Ext will look for class with the alias 'widget.MyPanel'.

Apart from this, I think your constructor is a bit funky looking. The constructor should not return itself (like you would do in a Perl constructor for instance)

This is enough:

```
constructor: function() {
     this.callParent(arguments);
     // Your own code here
}
```

Cheers and let me know if it helps
Rob

Answer (score 3):

all u have to do is declare it like that :

```
 var panel1 =  Ext.create('Ext.app.myPanel',{title : 'panel 1',height:350});//title and hight are optionals if u have already defined them
```

and then use it like this:

```
...
items : [panel1 ]
...
```

and  you may need to require it :

```
 Ext.require([
, 'Ext.app.myPanel'
]);
```

and put the mypanel.js an **app** folder

hope this helps